# infinitely recursive type in OCaml

Tags: recursion, types, ocaml

I'm reading this OCaml file and it contains the following:

```ml
type z = Z of z
```

This looks like z is infinitely recursive. How is it useful and how can I even construct such a type?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this type is particularly useful, except possibly as a test case in type theory.

You can construct values of the type like this:

```
# let rec x = Z x;;
val x : z = Z <cycle>
# let rec q = Z (Z q);;
val q : z = Z (Z <cycle>)
```

Once you have a value of the type you can readily construct other values of course:

```
# let y = Z (Z x);;
val y : z = Z (Z (Z <cycle>))
```

Comment: `type t = S of t | Z` makes sense for `let rec infinity = S infinity`.  We can imagine something like `let zip l1 (count1:t) l2 (count2:t) = ...` . I checked that `infinity` has matched with any of the following cases `S x`, `S (S x)`, `S (S (S x))` ... .